# How to search for a specific value in Firebase using Golang?

Tags: go, firebase

I am using Golang and Firego for connecting to Firebase. I am trying to search an admin with `Email: john@gmail.com`. The following is my Database Structure

[image: My Firebase Database Structure]

For this I have tried:

```
  dB.Child("CompanyAdmins").Child("Info").OrderBy("Email").EqualTo("john@gmail.com").Value(&result)
```

but it does not produce expected result. How can I do this?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @dev.bmax has the problem identified correctly, the solution is simpler. You can specify the path of a property to order on:

```
  dB.Child("CompanyAdmins")
    .OrderBy("Info/Email")
    .EqualTo("john@gmail.com")
    .Value(&result)
```

**Update** (2017-02-10):

Full code I just tried:

```
f := firego.New("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com", nil)

var result map[string]interface{}

if err := f.Child("42134844/CompanyAdmins").OrderBy("Info/Email").EqualTo("john@gmail.com").Value(&result); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s\n", result)
```

This prints:

> map[-K111111:map[Info:map[Email:john@gmail.com]]]

Which is the exact place where I put the data.

**Update 20170213**:

This is the index I have defined:

```
  "CompanyAdmins": {
    ".indexOn": "Info/Email"
  }
```

If this doesn't work for you, please provide a similarly complete snippet that I can test.

Comment: I have tried it but not working. I think the problem is with the query.

Comment: I just tested the code and added the snippet to my answer.

Comment: @SarathSankaraKurup I just tried the code above myself and it worked for me as well. Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffen, @zabawaba99 No! I got the following **"error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"Info/Email\", for path \"/CompanyAdmins\", to the rules"** and here is my rules: `{
  "rules": { 
    "CompanyAdmins": {
      "$userid": {
        "Info": {
          ".indexOn": ["Email"]
        }
      }
    },
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
  }
}`

Comment: Try updating your rules to `{"rules": {".read": true,".write": true,"CompanyAdmins": {".indexOn": ["Info/Email"]}}}`

Comment: @SarathSankaraKurup: I updated my answer to include the index. You need to move it one level higher in the JSON.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen It works! You saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you put Info data directly into CompanyAdmins structure? This way, your query will work.

```
CompanyAdmins
    -id
       -Email: "johndon@gmail.com"
       -Settings:
            - fields
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query, is that `Info` is not a direct child of `CompanyAdmins`.

You could use the email as the key instead of an auto-generated one when you insert values. That way, you can access the admin directly:

`dB.Child("CompanyAdmins").Child("john@gmail.com").Child("Info")`

Otherwise, you need to restructure the database. Your order-by field (email) should be one level higher, like Rodrigo Vinicius suggests. Then, your query will change to:

`dB.Child("CompanyAdmins").OrderBy("Email").EqualTo("john@gmail.com")`